# Lsqcurvefit tells me data is not the same size: Inaccurate?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am trying to obtain the parameters that fit my curve to my data.

Script 1: Executing the fit command.

```
tumor_Day = [5;8;11.25;17;18];
B0 = rand(6, 1);
[B,Rsdnrm,Rsd,ExFlg,OptmInfo,Lmda,Jmat] = lsqcurvefit(@Model1_Results,B0,tumor_Day,tumor_vol_norm);
```

Function 2: Model1_results.m

```
function tumorvol = Model1_Results(B, t)


%% Input Parameters
a11 = B(1);
a12 = B(2);
a13 = B(3);
a21 = B(4);
a22 = B(5);
a23 = B(6);
a31 = 1;
a32 = .1;
a41 = 3;
a51 = 3e-3;
C   = 0;
tau = 6;

%% Solve ODE 
tspan = [5 8 11.25 17 18];
x0 = [1 1 0 0 0];

[t, x] = ode45(@(t, x) liotta_model1(t, x,                          ...
                                     B(1), B(2), B(3), B(4), B(5), B(6),  ...
                                     a31, a32, a41, a51, C  , tau), ...
               tspan, x0);

 tumorvol = x(:,1);

end
```

Function 3: liotta_model1.m (odefunction)

```
    function dxdt = liotta_model1(t, x, ...
                              a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23, a31, a32, a41, a51, ...
                              C, tau)

b1 = a11*(x(2)/x(1))/(a12 + (x(2)/x(1)));
d1 = a13*(x(1)/x(2))^2;

b2 = (a21*b1)/(a22+b1);
d2 = a23*d1;

dxdt(1) = (b1 - d1)*x(1);
dxdt(2) = (b2 - d2)*x(2);
dxdt(3) = a31*x(2) - a32*x(3);
dxdt(4) = a32*x(3) - a41*x(4);
dxdt(5) = a51*x(4)*heaviside(x(4) - C);

% Convert to column vector as required by ode45
dxdt = dxdt(:);

end
```

My experimental data, time points and objective function results are all of the same size:

```
tumor_vol_norm =

    1.0000
    1.5000
    2.6250
    3.5000
    3.5000


t =

    5.0000
    8.0000
   11.2500
   17.0000
   18.0000

Model1_Results(B0, t)

ans =

    1.0000
    1.3142
    2.2052
    7.2455
    9.1094
```

But I still receive this error:

**Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in lsqcurvefit/objective (line 265)
         F = F - YDATA;**

Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inaccurate?` *not*. The code is working exactly as programmed to do, and giving the expected error.

`lsqcurvefit` requires your function `Model1_Results` to output a vector the same size as your ydata vector `tumor_vol_norm`, which has 5 elements.

However, `ode45` will not always output a 5 element vector. Often with optimization the function being minimized will fail for some values that the optimizer tries.  You need to protect against those and substitute in values that will not stop the code from working, but indicate that the set of parameters currently being trialed are *bad*.

For most optimization routines, such as `fmincon` and `fminunc` where the function you specify is the actual cost then that's relatively simple, and can just involve wrapping the code in a `try-catch` block and if it fails output a cost that is relatively large.  That tells the optimizer that these aren't good values and to continue looking elsewhere in the solution space.

For `lsqcurvefit` it can be a bit more problematic, since your functiondoesn't directly output the cost.  Rather it outputs a vector of `y_hat` values that `lsqcurvefit` then uses itself to calculate the cost.

In your case there's an additional problem because the failure in `ode45` only raises a warning, not an error.  To get around that you want to do something like the following:

```
function tumorvol = Model1_Results(B, t)

%% Input Parameters
a11 = B(1);
a12 = B(2);
a13 = B(3);
a21 = B(4);
a22 = B(5);
a23 = B(6);
a31 = 1;
a32 = .1;
a41 = 3;
a51 = 3e-3;
C   = 0;
tau = 6;

%% Solve ODE 
tspan = [5 8 11.25 17 18];
x0 = [1 1 0 0 0];

try
   [t, x] = ode45(@(t, x) liotta_model1(t, x,...
            B(1), B(2), B(3), B(4), B(5), B(6),...
            a31, a32, a41, a51, C  , tau),...
            tspan, x0);

   tumorvol = x(:);
   if ~all(size(x)==size(x0))
      tumorvol = 1e10*ones(numel(x0),1);
   end
catch ME
   tumorvol = 1e10*ones(numel(x0),1);
end

end
```

Comment: Wait, but tumor_vol_norm has 5 elements up there.

Comment: I've updated my answer, which you are correct, indicated the size mismatch was due to something that it wasn't due to.